# Usage of the phrase "over his lifetime"

Tags: phrases, appropriate

Is it appropriate to use the phrase "over his lifetime" for in introducing someone if the person is still alive, i.e. "...his dedication to music over his lifetime..."

Comment: I think it's fine, though it might be safer to say  "*throughout* his lifetime" or "*for his whole life*".

Comment: It's fine.  (When I opened this question I was worried that it was another question about whether it meant his *entire* lifetime, or just his lifetime through yesterday.  Or how could we know he's dedicated to music over his entire lifetime when he might live another 50 years and spend those years hating music.)

Answer (score 1):

"**during his lifetime**" is ok.

"He has dedicated himself entirely to music during his lifetime."

> "During his lifetime Van Gogh was never famous as a painter."
>
> "During his lifetime Prince Charles (still alive) has always tried to ..."

Comment: OP's problem is the person he's celebrating, unlike Van Gogh, is still alive (and he's specifically worried about implying the guy has died).

Comment: @DanBron Ok, I've added someone who is still alive.

Comment: Cool. For OP's sake, you might want to make a similar change to the tense of your first (critical) example about music.

Answer (score 0):

While introducing someone.... [Lifetime](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lifetime): Occurring or measured over a person's active career:

> A lifetime of dedication to music..
>
> A lifetime batting average.